# ¿Por qué mi arreglo imprime solo los últimos valores que le agrego?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo este pequeño programa, soy nuevo en C++ y estoy usando un arreglo bidimensional, necesito hacer un programa que registre las ventas de sucursales por meses, sin embargo después de registrar, al imprimir los datos todas las sucursales me salen con los mismos datos de las ventas.

```
int meses;
int sucursales;
double Datos[sucursales][meses];


// Solicitar cantidad de sucursales a evaluar y meses a registrar

cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de sucursales a evaluar: ";
cin >> sucursales;

cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de meses a registrar: ";
cin >> meses;


for(int i= 0; i < sucursales; i++)
{
    cout<<"Ingresa por favor los datos de la sucursal "<<i + 1<<" del arreglo:"<<endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < meses; j++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese el total de ventas del mes "<<j + 1<<": ";
        cin>>Datos[i][j];
        cout<<"guardado en:"<<i<<j<<endl;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < sucursales; i++)
{
    cout<<"De la sucursal: "<<i+1<<"\nLos montos de las ventas registradas por mes son:"<<endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < meses; j++)
    {
        cout<<"Mes "<<j+1<<": "<<Datos[i][j]<<endl;
        cout<<"sacado de:"<<i<<j<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ese código no debería ni compilar. El tamaño de un arreglo debe conocerse en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, estás definiendo el arreglo con tamaños desconocidos:

```
int meses;      // ¿Cuál es el valor de 'meses'?
int sucursales; // ¿Cuál es el valor de 'sucursales'?
double Datos[sucursales][meses]; // ¿Qué tamaño tiene 'Datos'?
```

Para acabar, el tamaño no se reajusta *automágicamente* cuando pides los tamaños:

```
cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de sucursales a evaluar: ";
cin >> sucursales; // Das valor a 'sucursales' pero 'Datos' no se ve afectado.

cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de meses a registrar: ";
cin >> meses; // Das valor a 'meses' pero 'Datos' no se ve afectado.
```

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>1</sup> el tamaño de las formaciones <sup>2</sup> debe conocerse en tiempo de compilación, una variable (por definición) es un valor que se conoce en tiempo de ejecución. En caso contrario, incurres en [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) que puede provocar que tu programa no funcione o de funcionar puede hacerlo de manera errática, como estás viendo.

Si quieres una colección de datos de tamaño conocido en tiempo de ejecución, no uses formaciones usa contenedores de la librería estándar:

```
using periodo_mensual = std::vector<double>;
using sucursales_activas = std::vector<periodo_mensual>;

std::cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de sucursales a evaluar: ";
std::cin >> sucursales;

std::cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de meses a registrar: ";
std::cin >> meses;

// Creamos una colección de 'sucursales_activas' con 'sucursales' elementos
// siendo cada elemento un 'periodo_mensual' de tamaño 'meses'
sucursales_activas Datos(sucursales, periodo_mensual(meses));
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Y otros lenguajes de programación.

###### <sup>2</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.